# JSP:how can i get a data from html form to java class

Tags: jsp

You know that we need a java class for writing a custom tag library. So I want to write my own tag lib. But I must take a data from the html form in the jsp page. How can i get a data from a html form to my java class?

Comment: By looking at the request parameters?

Comment: Please elaborate more on your requirement with the custom tag

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve the `HttpServletRequest` from your page context. In your tag library just use this to get it:

```
PageContext pageContext = (PageContext) getJspContext();  
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) pageContext.getRequest();
```

For e.g.: You have a html form in your JSP page:

```
<form action="/someServlet">
   <input type="text" value="yourValue" name="yourParameterName"/>
</form>
```

To get your parameter use:

```
String yourValue = request.getParameter("yourParameterName");
```